# Is there a term that extends the Real Subsumption of Labour to society as a whole?

Tags: marxism, social-ethics, philosophy-of-culture, capitalism

I am currently doing some research on Marx's concept of Real Subsumption of Labour, which refers to the process of capitalist production transforming from a formal subsumption (using pre-existing methods of production) to a real subsumption (using new methods of production to fully control and extract surplus value from workers).

However, I am wondering if there is a term that extends this concept beyond just the realm of labor, and to society as a whole. Specifically, I am interested in exploring if there is a term that describes the process of capitalism extending its control and dominance beyond just labor, and into the social and cultural spheres.

My initial thoughts are that this concept could possibly relate to Marx's idea of the commodification of culture, where cultural products are turned into commodities to be bought and sold on the market. However, I am unsure if this fully captures the extent of capitalist control over society as a whole.

If anyone has any insights or suggestions on this topic, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I hadn't thought about this aspect of Marxism before. My first thought is that without surplus value, nothing would ever change, improve or be created. Bare survival isn't much of a life. Second, I think the potential realm of Capitalism (which I just think of as getting paid to provide something) is unlimited. Anything can be a commodity. The capitalist system is a spinning machine with no governor, no top speed. "*Four*"